# Tournament bracket rounds not updating with winner when entering scores in previous round

Tags: typescript, recursion, svelte

I am learning Svelte and wanted to create a tournament bracket that automatically chooses winners for the next round.

The problem arises when I try to enter the scores and try to show the winner of the next round. When I enter a score in the starting round such as `temp8 -> 2`, the winning team should automatically be placed in the next round (against `temp1` in this case).

I don't know what to try at this point. Passing copies of the bracket between recursive iterations of the `createMatches` function doesn't do anything, and passing a copy from the svelte code doesn't do anything either. I am pretty sure that my logic inside the function does its job correctly. Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated greatly.

Here is an image of the problem:

[image: the problem]

I have the following svelte code to create the bracket:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { createMatches } from "$lib/handlers/bracketupdate";
  import type { Bracket } from "$lib/types/bracket";
  export let bracket: Bracket;
  export let readonly = false;

  $: bracket = createMatches(bracket);
</script>

<div class="bracket">
  {#each Object.keys(bracket.scores)
    .sort((a, b) => +a - +b)
    .map((k) => +k) as round}
    <div class="round">
      {#each bracket.scores[round] as match}
        <div class="match">
          <div class="team">
            <p>{match.team1._id}</p>
            <input type="number" bind:value={match.team1_score} {readonly} />
          </div>
          <div class="team">
            <p>{match.team2._id}</p>
            <input type="number" bind:value={match.team2_score} {readonly} />
          </div>
        </div>
      {/each}
    </div>
  {/each}
</div>
```

I am using the following functions to create the bracket:

```js
import { bye, type Bracket, type BracketMatch, pending } from "$lib/types/bracket";
import type { Team } from "$lib/types/teams";

export function createMatches(bracket: Bracket, round = 0): Bracket {
  // Base case
  if (bracket.teams.length < 2) return bracket;

  if (round === 0) {
    // Add byes to make the number of teams a power of 2
    const numByes = 2 ** Math.ceil(Math.log2(bracket.teams.length)) - bracket.teams.length;
    if (numByes > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < numByes; i++) {
        bracket.teams.push(bye);
      }
    }

    // Shuffle the teams by seed
    bracket.teams = shuffle(bracket.teams);
  }

  // Create matches for this round
  const matches: BracketMatch[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < bracket.teams.length; i += 2) {
    const team1 = bracket.teams[i];
    const team2 = bracket.teams[i + 1];

    matches.push({ team1, team2, team1_score: 0, team2_score: 0 });
  }

  // Add the matches to the bracket
  bracket.scores[round] = matches;

  // Create the next round
  const winners = getWinners(matches);
  bracket.teams = winners;
  createMatches(bracket, round + 1);

  return bracket;
}

function getWinners(matches: BracketMatch[]) {
  return matches.map((match) => {
    if (match.team1._id === bye._id) return match.team2;
    if (match.team2._id === bye._id) return match.team1;

    if (match.team1_score > match.team2_score) return match.team1;
    if (match.team2_score > match.team1_score) return match.team2;

    return pending;
  });
}

function shuffle(teams: Team[]) {
  // Create a copy of the teams array
  let result = [...teams];

  // Calculate and loop for the number of rounds
  const numRounds = Math.log2(teams.length / 2);
  for (let i = 0; i < numRounds; i++) {
    // Create a new round
    const round = [];

    // Calculate the number of teams to splice
    const splice = Math.pow(2, i);

    // Loop while there are still teams to splice
    while (result.length) {
      round.push(...result.splice(0, splice));
      round.push(...result.splice(-splice));
    }

    // Set the round to the result
    result = round;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: `$: bracket = createMatches(bracket);` is not good. It would recreate the bracket on any change. I would separate the initial round creation and shuffling into a separate function from building the bracket tree and only execute it once.

Comment: Also, where is the recursion for the later rounds?

Comment: You can probably solve this by making each "round" a svelte store consisting of an array of each matches (teams, winner) and have each subsequent subscribe to the previous to populate itself.

Comment: @brunnerh Recursion for the later rounds for the later rounds happens in `createMatches` under the comment `// Create next round`

Comment: @StephaneVanraes That seems like it would only work for a set amount of teams, if I changed the number of teams, the number of stores would also have to change right?

Comment: @mhay10: I meant the recursion in the UI. `createMatches` is not called with a `round` argument and there is no `<svelte:self>` or the like anywhere.

Comment: @brunnerh There is none in the UI. `createMatches` generates the bracket beforehand and then it gets rendered. Would using `<svelte:self>` be a better option?

Comment: That depends, for a bracket actually maybe not, for a tree it might be. If you use a component recursively, then going from big to small is easier due to the hierarchical structure of the DOM. So in same cases it makes layout easier but here it might even get in the way.